# NET MVC 5: Update only one field in the Database

Tags: c#, html, mysql, url, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to update only one filed of the DB. I am creating a function in my Controller (AOProf Controller) that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Accommodation_App.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Accommodation_App.Controllers
{
    public class AOProfController : Controller
    {

        private StudAccommodationEntities1 SContextUser;
        private DbSet<User> UserDb;

        private StudAccommodationEntities1Entities SContextProp;
        private DbSet<Property> Properties;

        public AOProfController()
        {
            SContextUser = new StudAccommodationEntities1();
            UserDb = SContextUser.UserDb;

            SContextProp = new StudAccommodationEntities1Entities();
            Properties = SContextProp.Properties;
        }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reject(int id)
{

    Property obj = Properties.Find(id);
    if (obj != null)
    {
        obj.isApproved = false;
        UpdateModel(obj);
        SContextProp.SaveChanges();

    }

    else{
        return Content("Not such an object");    
     }
    return Content("the rejected is confirmed");
}
```

And in my view I call this function from the onclick event. I sent the param before to the view. It is send correctly.

```
  <button value="Reject" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Reject", "AOProf", new { id = item.ProId })'" >Reject</button>
```

The url that appears in the URL bar after clicking the button is

```
http://localhost:54464/AOProf/Reject/1
```

It looks fine, but the record won't update in the database. It will stay the same. Can you please, help me to understand how to to do it the right way?

Comment: `location.href` makes a redirect to a GET method (not a POST method). But since your changing data it should be a POST. Use a form with a submit button to POST to that method.

Comment: Yes, I replaced the POST method with GET. This is one important step of the solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: If the method is changing data, it should be  POST, not a GET!

Comment: Yes, but in my case, I have no form in my View. I identified that I had a typo in my Model. I used "isApproved" instead of "IsApproved". It works now. Thank you! :)

Comment: Then add a form!